# Factorial of a number using a while loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need help creating the code  to find the factorial of a number. The task is to

1. Create a variable to store your answer and initialize it to one
2. Create a loop that beings at the given value, fact
3. Check if fact is one or zero
4. multiply fact with your answer variable
5. At the end of the loop decrease fact
6. Print answer using console.log

The pseudocode is

```
while(factorial)
  if factorial == 0 or factorial == 1
    break 
  result => result * factorial
  factorial  => factorial - 1
```

My code below isn't complete because I'm confused by the pseudocode.

```
function nth_fact(nth){
var a = 1
while(nth_fact)
if (nth_fact == 0 || nth_fact == 1){
    break;
result => result * nth_fact
nth_fact => nth - 1
console.log() 
}
}
```

Comment: `nth_fact` is a function, take `nth`

Comment: `=>` is an arrow function, you want the assinment operator `=`

Comment: What is `=>` doing in your pseudocode?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You used the right approach. Just the syntax was wrong. Here it is:

```
function nth_fact(nth){
var result = 1 ;
while(nth){
  if ((nth) == 0 || (nth) == 1)
    break ;
  result = result * nth;
  nth = nth - 1
 }
console.log(result); 
return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you really think you help the OP with this??

Answer (score 3):

At first lets examine what went wrong:

```
var a = 1
```

What is `a`? Its definetly not a good name for a variable. Maybe name it to `result` ? The same applies to `nth` which should be named `factorial` and `nth_fact` which should rather be `factorize` or sth. You should also always use `;` to end a statement.

```
while(nth_fact)
```

As your while loop contains multiple statements (the `if` and the two assignments) you need to open a block here by using `{` right after the condition. `nth_fact` refers to the function, you rather want to take `factorial` here.

```
 if (nth_fact == 0 || nth_fact == 1){
   break;
```

Now you open a block statement for the if, but you never close it. So you need another `}` after the break.

```
result => result * nth_fact
nth_fact => nth - 1
console.log()
```

`=>` is the arrow function expression, but you want the assignment operator `=`. Also you need to pass something to console.log, e.g. `console.log(result)`

All together:

```
 function factorize(factorial){
   var result = 1;
  while(factorial){
     if (factorial == 0 || factorial == 1){
        break;
     }
     // ?
     factorial = factorial - 1;
     console.log(result);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That pseudocode is indeed confusing, because what it calls `factorial` is actually not the factorial -- it's the current value, which the result (which is actually the factorial we're looking for) is multiplied by. Also, `if` is superfluous, because `while` already checks for the same condition. So the correct pseudocode would be

```
currentValue = argument
factorial = 1

while (currentValue > 1)
    factorial = factorial * currentValue
    currentValue = currentValue - 1

// now, 'factorial' is the factorial of the 'argument'
```

Once you get this sorted out, here's a bonus assignment:

- create a function `range(a, b)` that creates an array of numbers from `a` to `b`. For example, `range(5, 8) => [5, 6, 7, 8]`
- create a function `product(array)` that multiples array elements by each other. For example, `product([2, 3, 7]) => 42`
- write the factorial function using `product` and `range`

Answer (score 1):

**I solve this this way**

```js
function factorial(number) {
  let num = 1;
  let result = 1;
  while (num <= number) {
    result = result * num;
    num++;
  }
  return result;
}
const myNumber = factorial(6);
console.log(myNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function factorial(num) {
         var result = 1
         while (num) {
            if ((num) == 0 || (num) == 1) {
               break;
            } else {
               result = result * num;
               num = num - 1;
            }
         }
         return `The factorial of ${val} is ${result}`
      }

      let val = prompt("Please Enter the number : ", "0");
      var x = parseInt(val);
      console.log(factorial(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

A Short And Clean Code is :

```js
let number = 5;
let numberFactorial = number;
    while(number > 1){
        numberFactorial = numberFactorial * (number-1);
        number--;
    }
console.log(numberFactorial);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
function factorize(factorial) {
    if(factorial == 0 | factorial == 1) {
        return 1
    }
    else{
        var result = factorial;
        while(factorial >= 1 ){

            if(factorial-1 == 0) {
                break
            };

            result = result * (factorial - 1);

            factorial = factorial-1;

            //DEBUG: console.log(factorial + ' ' +  result);
        };
        return(result);
    }
}
```

If you want more info about functions, can see in my GitHub, good learning!
Github: https://github.com/bennarthurdev/JavaScript/tree/main/FUNCOES